# Should I volatile the field with synchronized methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

With following class,

```java
// This class should be thread-safe!!!
class BankAccount {

    private long balance; // Should it be volatile?

    synchronized void deposit(long amount) {
        // ...
        balance += amount;
    }

    synchronized void withdraw(long amount) {
        // ...
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

Should I add `volatile` to `balance` field?

Answer (score 4):

No, compared with `synchronized` keyword, `volatile` is lightweight.

`volatile` can gurantee the reader thread always get fresh `balance` value, but it can not make `balance += amount;` atomic. `synchronized` can do both.

Comment: Would getter have to be `synchronized` or it doesn't matter (i.e. it will be returning the update value anyway, because the update was in the synchronised block)?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak If the field is not `volatile`, it's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need `volatile` in the code shown, because the variable is used only within the `synchronized` methods. The `synchronized` methods make sure that the variable’s contents are visible and not stale, and also make sure that the operations performed within each `synchronized` method are not interfered with by concurrently running threads. The `volatile` keyword is redundant here, it only makes sure the variable’s contents are visible.

If you want the variable’s value to be visible to threads that don’t enter a `synchronized` instance method on this object (maybe you’d like it to be used in methods that don’t acquire a lock on the instance), then in that case keeping it `volatile` would make sense.

If you took away the `synchronized` keywords and left the variable `volatile`, you’d have a problem, because although `volatile` makes sure updates are visible it doesn’t make sure the updates are atomic. The `+=` and `-=` operations here are not atomic and can be interfered with by concurrently-running threads.

Alternatively consider using an [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) instead, in this example you might not need the `synchronized` keyword (depending on what the code in //... does). Methods like [`addAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#addAndGet-long-) perform their changes to the value stored atomically. For most things where you would have used volatile before, the Atomic classes can do a better job.